# How can I check if AdSense is showing ads in other countries?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, traffic, country-specific

I have build website and it is showing AdSense ads in India.
How can I check whether ads are showing in the USA or Canada?

Is there any minimum traffic requirement for showing ads in each country?

Answer (score 1):

Go into your AdSense reporting and click on the "Countries" report.  It will tell you how often ads on your site are showing up in each country.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ads should be showing up in all countries.

To check if they are you can use a VPN.
Tunnel Bear is free and gives you the ability to choose they country you want to connect from.
[Tunnel bear link](https://www.tunnelbear.com/)